# refreshing web page after Database changes without frameworks ? messaging application

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is it possible to refresh a web page when changes are made to the database without a framework? I've tried looking for an answer but all seem to include some type of framework to accomplish this. I don't like learning a new framework unless it's completely necessary. I am trying to make a messaging app. I can receive messages from others that are signed in but only if I refresh the page. Is there a solution to this, or maybe a different approach to take ? would learning a framework be completely necessary to accomplish this ? Here is my code to print a messages sent from another user, I named the other user bill in this case:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli($server_name,$server_username,$server_password,$dbname);

$bill = $conn ->query("SELECT message_sent FROM message WHERE name = 'bill'");
while($row = $bill->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo $row["message_sent"];
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean the page on which you made the change, or all instances of that page open on other browsers? If it's the latter you need a pub/sub system and the reason a framework is often used is because setting that up from scratch is really annoying and hard.

Comment: it would be all instances of that page open on other browsers. any suggestions on a good framework for this then?

Comment: Sounds like a job for something like [Socket.io](https://socket.io) plus a bunch of other server-side integration. I know you're using PHP, but as an example I'm more familiar with, [Ruby on Rails](https://rubyonrails.org) does this real-time communication out of the box as of version 5.2. PHP solutions like [Laravel](https://laravel.com) require adding things like [Pusher](https://github.com/ruudk/pusher-php-server) to the mix. You still have to do a lot of work to set up a proper [Observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) structure in either case.

Comment: You may want to look at [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com) as an example of something that does exactly what you want, even if not PHP. As far as I know it has a complete real-time observer structure for your applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly simply just using 2 files - `index.php` which displays a HTML page, and `get_messages.php` which serves up the latest messages.

This does use a bit of [jQuery to do the server-side fetching](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) but it's more of a library than a framework ;)

The `index.php` HTML page sends a request to `get-messages.php` every 3 seconds, updating the page with any new messages.

The server-side script `get_messages.php` also randomly creates messages, so you can see instant results... once you've seen it in action, you can delete everything between the `// --- BEGIN FAKE MESSAGE CREATION --- //` and `// --- END FAKE MESSAGE CREATION --- //` comments and add your own database code in the appropriate place.

Hopefully I've added enough comments to explain what happens, where & why!

### index.php

```
<?php

// --- BEGIN FAKE MESSAGE CREATION --- //
session_start();
unset( $_SESSION[ 'messages' ] );
// --- END FAKE MESSAGE CREATION --- //

?>
<!--DOCTYPE HTML -->
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Messages</title>
<!-- Load jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Messages</h1>

<!-- This <div> is where messages will be displayed -->
<div id="message_list"></div>

<script>
function get_messages() {
  // Load messages from the server
  $.ajax({
    url: 'get_messages.php',
    success: function(result){
      // Insert the result into <div id="message_list">
      $("#message_list").html(result);
    }
  });
}

// Wait for the page to load...
$(document).ready( function() {
  // Get messages straight away
  get_messages();
  // Call get_messages() every 3 seconds
  setInterval( get_messages, 3000 );  
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

### get_messages.php

```
<?php
// --- BEGIN FAKE MESSAGE CREATION --- //
session_start();

// Maybe create a new message?
if ( !rand( 0, 3 ) )  
  $_SESSION[ 'messages' ][] = md5( time() );

$messages = $_SESSION[ 'messages' ];
// --- END FAKE MESSAGE CREATION --- //

echo '<p>Last updated: ' . date( 'H:i:s' ) . '</p>';

// *** This is where you'd loop through your database entries *** //
foreach ( $messages as $m )
  echo $m . '<br>';

?>
```

I'm aware this is far from the most elegant solution, but hopefully it's a nice simple example - one improvement would be to return only new messages, and appending them to the existing list (to save bandwidth etc)... but I'll leave that for you to figure out!